# Identify this 1990s-era educational game featuring kohlrabi

Tags: identify-this-game

I have fond memories of several educational computer games from school circa 1993–1998. Possibly from [MECC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MECC), but I haven't found this game on any lists of MECC games as far as I could tell.

It's a simulation, similar to [Hammurabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamurabi_(video_game)) or [Lemonade Stand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemonade_Stand). It did have color graphics, though; it wasn't purely text-based. (This was the era of CGA/EGA/VGA graphics options.)

It's a farming/gardening simulation. You have a greenhouse where you can plant various vegetable crops. The only vegetable I'm 99% confident was involved was "kohlrabi." I remembered that one because this was the first place I'd heard of it, and I still didn't really know what it was until years later. Other vegetables you could plant might have included peas, corn, string beans, that kind of thing.

I think there was a weather aspect (X probability of sunny weather, X probability of cloudy weather), and you had to decide how much to water the plants, and so on. I don't really remember the parameters of the simulation.

There were several other simulation games on the same computer; I don't know if they might have been packaged together. One involved making model rockets; one involved racing cars and featured a wind-tunnel screen; one was definitely [*Odell Lake*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odell_Lake_(video_game)).

Comment: It does not quite sound like SimFarm, but perhaps worth having a look...

Comment: You remember what kind of computer?  Apple II?

Comment: "You remember what kind of computer? Apple II?" — My impression is of a PC, but I think I'm misremembering the Apple II as being more primitive than it really was. My game definitely had multi-color graphics (probably 320x200), but I see from Wikipedia that the Apple II could do that. So yes, it could have been an Apple II/IIe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Lunar Greenhouse* for the Apple IIe features kohlrabi:

- http://www.virtualapple.org/lunargreenhouse.html
- https://www.mobygames.com/game/lunar-greenshouse

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thanks! And here's the archive.org link where (at least as of July 2021) you can play it online: https://archive.org/details/MECC-A215_Lunar_Greenhouse